# Split a JSON to multiple lines using UNIX command line tools

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, cut

We have a JSON file that needs to be multi-lined instead of being single lined as shown below,

```
{this is the first block},{this is the second block, really},{this is the third you're kidding:no}
```

We expected it to be like this so that it can be fed to an external program to read it without issues,

```
{this is the first block}
{this is the second block, really}
{this is the third you're kidding:no}
```

I'm not an expert with simple text processing tools like awk, sed, cut but I did try with sed for sometime unsuccessfully.

```
cat test.json | sed 's/},/\n/g'
{this is the first block
{this is the second block, really
{this is the third you're kidding:no}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: seems like you  need `}\n` instead of `\n` in your sed attempt

Comment: Your inputs are not JSON

Comment: To be JSON, it would need to be in an array, starting with `[` and ending with `]`. Is that the case for your real data?

Comment: (if so, `jq -c '.[]' <infile.json` will do the job).

Comment: To illustrate @CharlesDuffy's comment `echo '[{"a":0},{"b":1},{"c":2}]' | jq -c '.[]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is not JSON and you just want to split:

`input_file`

```
{this is the first block},{this is the second block, really},{this is the third you're kidding:no}
```

```sh
sed 's/},/}\n/g' input_file
```

`output`

```
{this is the first block}
{this is the second block, really}
{this is the third you're kidding:no}
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk alternative:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="(,?{)|(},?)" } /[[:alnum:]]/ { print $0="{"$0"}" }' file
```

Set the records separator to one or more commas and { or } and one or more commas. Then, when an alpha numeric string is encountered, prefix { to the string, append } and print